# How to create a set of progressive text+numbers index

Tags: r, sequence

I'm new to R.
I have a weekly time-series dataset and the date column looks like:

```
1/10/2004
1/17/2004
1/24/2004
1/31/2004
2/7/2004

.
.
1/3/2015
1/10/2015
```

I want to create an index that looks like this (W stands for week):

```
2004W1
2004W2
.
.
2004W52
2005W1
2005W2
.
.
.
2015W1
2015W2
```

What could be a right code? Can I use the function ts to do it? I tried this:

```
data=ts(mydata,start=c(2004,1),freq=48)
```

But it doesn't do the job

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `POSIXlt` : It doesn't have a $week element but you can use modulo division:

```
 vec = c("1/10/2004", "1/17/2004", "1/24/2004")
 paste0("20", as.POSIXlt(vec, format="%m/%d/%Y")$year, "W", as.POSIXlt(vec, format="%m/%d/%Y")$yday %/% 7)
#[1] "20104W1" "20104W2" "20104W3"
```